# First stackoverflow question Daily coding problem #7

Tags: javascript

i am working on my Daily coding problem # 7 and having a hard time finding a way to test this algorithm to see if it will work. 
Here is the Question:

Good morning! Here's your coding interview problem for today.

This problem was asked by Facebook.

Given the mapping a = 1, b = 2, ... z = 26, and an encoded message, count the number of ways it can be decoded.

For example, the message '111' would give 3, since it could be decoded as 'aaa', 'ka', and 'ak'.

### You can assume that the messages are decodable. For example, '001' is not allowed.

This is the solution i found. Any idea how i can confirm this will decode?

```
function numDecodingsRHelper(message, index) {
  if (index === message.length) return 1;
  if (message.charAt(index) === '0') return 0;

  // Single Number
  let totalDecodings = numDecodingsRHelper(message, index + 1);
  if (index < message.length - 1) {
    // Double Number
    const doubleNum = parseInt(message.substring(index, index + 2), 10);

    if (doubleNum >= 10 && doubleNum <= 26)
      totalDecodings += numDecodingsRHelper(message, index + 2);
  }
  return totalDecodings;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Why not try running the code against some tests to see if it matches your expectations?

Answer (score 0):

This is the better solution. The problem with several other solutions that i found they were only returning a list of possible sequences of letters from a string input instead of returning the total number as a whole number. As in, like the example used in the question '111' returns 3 but most of the solutions i found would return a list like  'aaa', 'ka', and 'ak'.

```
 function decode_cnt_no_zero(message) {

let length = message.length

if (length <=1) { return 1 }

if (length >=2) { var parsed = parseInt(message.substring(0,2),10) if (parsed >=0 && parsed <= 26) { return (decode_cnt_no_zero(message.substring(1,length)) + decode_cnt_no_zero(message.substring(2, length))) } return decode_cnt_no_zero(message.substring(1, length)) } }
```